# Extract the current namespace, bundle, controller and action name symfony3

Tags: php, symfony

I need dynamic functions to get the current namespace,bundle, controller and action name in symfony3 controller

Comment: why? what you need to do? what have you tried?

Comment: we have general delete controller I need BundleName to do some work related to the project workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php).

Here's a little example from the [official doc](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getnamespacename.php#refsect1-reflectionclass.getnamespacename-examples), which extracts the namespace and the class name:

```
<?php
namespace A\B;

class Foo { }

$class = new \ReflectionClass('stdClass');

var_dump($class->inNamespace());
var_dump($class->getName());
var_dump($class->getNamespaceName());
var_dump($class->getShortName());

$class = new \ReflectionClass('A\\B\\Foo');

var_dump($class->inNamespace());
var_dump($class->getName());
var_dump($class->getNamespaceName());
var_dump($class->getShortName());
?>
```

Output:

```
bool(false)
string(8) "stdClass"
string(0) ""
string(8) "stdClass"

bool(true)
string(7) "A\B\Foo"
string(3) "A\B"
string(3) "Foo"
```